# Getting a vaule in a link for later usage in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a link on my webpage which I need to get the value from and save in for later usage (constructing a direct URL).

The html-link I want to obtain the value from look like this:

```
<a ng-bind="saving.customerContractName || (saving| savingscontract:$parent.$parent.cmsData) " ng-attr-target="{{(saving.type === 'ASK') ? '_blank' : undefined}}" ng-href="/lpn/mo/Logon.action?avtalenummer=176742" class="ng-binding" target="" href="/lpn/mo/Logon.action?avtalenummer=176742">Fondskonto Link (176742)</a>
```

The value I need to obtain is 176742.

Any tips on how to extract this value? And further use it in a direct URL call (something) like this:

```
String url2 = "https://www2-t.storebrand.no/ppjs/#/savings/index/THE_VALUE_HERE";
    driver.get(url2);
```

Answer (score 0):

this might work.

```
txt = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Fondskonto Link").get_attribute("href").split("=")[1]
url = "https://www2-t.storebrand.no/ppjs/#/savings/index/%s" % txt
driver.get(url)
```